# Why does UIBezierPath behave like this?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, nodes, uibezierpath, cgpath

I make a little SpriteKit game where the enemies are following a UIBezierPath. (Is there btw any other way to do this? It seems pretty unproductive)

Anyway my enemy behaves very strange. Here's the code for a simple circle with a diameter of 300:

```
    enemy.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    UIBezierPath* circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];

    CGPathRef pathRef = [cicrlePath CGPath];


    SKAction *followPath = [SKAction followPath:pathRef
                                       asOffset:NO
                                   orientToPath:NO
                                       duration: pathSpeed];




    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followPath];


    [enemy runAction:forever];
```

Now see how I specified the enemies position and the circlePath position at (0,0)?

Somehow it's giving me this result:  http://www.gfycat.com/DistinctSnarlingAracari

It's not really making sense since it's way out of place, I think? Or am I missing something?

**Oh, and like I mentioned before, how could I do enemy movements for my game the most efficient/productive way? I am currently using PaintCode with UIBeziers, but it's always giving me a strange result. I am really looking forward to your answers..**

Comment: What exactly is wrong in your GIF?  If you think the “1” icon is in the wrong place, where do you expect it to be?

Comment: Well since the default anchor point for a Sprite Kit scene is in the lower left corner (as seen here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW19)

I expect the 1 to be only visible in the lower left corner

EDIT: I just realized my fault: I thought it would use the center of the BezierPath to position it's path..

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't understand `-[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:]` or maybe `CGRectMake`.  Your `0, 0` is the upper-left corner of the bounding box of the oval, not the center, and `300, 300` is the width and height of that bounding box.  If you want the oval to be centered at `0, 0`, try this:

```
UIBezierPath* circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
    CGRectMake(-150, -150, 300, 300)];
```

Comment: yeah, makes sense now. However do you know a better way to create enemy paths for my game? It seems like a bit of a hassle the way I'm doing it now

Comment: I have little experience with game development tools.

Comment: In any case what does "a hassle" mean? That's just a vague, touchy-feely, meaningless matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The center of a UIBezier oval path is at (x + width/2, y + height/2). Starting from angle = 0 (right-most point on the oval i.e., (x+width,y+height/2)), ovals are drawn counter-clockwise in scene coordinates. A sprite will, therefore, follow an oval path in a counter-clockwise direction because it moves in the same direction in which the path was drawn.

Here's code that may be useful to you:

This method creates an oval path that is centered at the position (origin) of the specified CGRect.

```
- (CGPathRef) ovalInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat width = rect.size.width;
    CGFloat height = rect.size.height;
    CGFloat x = rect.origin.x-rect.size.width/2;
    CGFloat y = rect.origin.y-rect.size.height/2;

    return[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)].CGPath;
}
```

This method creates an SKAction that moves a node along a circular path. The parameters
specifies the center, radius, and direction (YES = clockwise and NO = counter-clockwise) of the path.

```
- (SKAction *) createCircularPathActionAtLocation:(CGPoint)center
                                       withRadius:(CGFloat)radius
                                  andDirectionCW:(BOOL)directionCW

{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(center.x, center.y, radius*2, radius*2);
    CGPathRef ovalPath = [self ovalInRect:rect];
    SKAction *circlePathAction = [SKAction followPath:ovalPath asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:5];
    SKAction *action;

    if (directionCW) {
        // Reverse the action to follow the path in the opposite direction
        action = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[circlePathAction reversedAction]];
    }
    else {
        action = [SKAction repeatActionForever:circlePathAction];
    }
    return action;
}
```

Side note: If you are using PaintCode 2, you can generalize the code it produces by using variables instead of absolute values.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! You mentioned that PaintCode 2 can generalize the code by using variables, how would that be different (to using absolute values) and where do I find this option?

Comment: It's the last item in the panel on the left under Images.